# Easy Thumbnails not working on Ubuntu

Tags: python, django, easy-thumbnails

I've been using Django [Easy Thumbnails](https://github.com/SmileyChris/easy-thumbnails) and it works very nicely in my local development server on Mac OS X. But I can't get it to run in my Ubuntu production environment. I get no errors (DEBUG is set to True), it just doesn't generate the image nor does it return the URL. I have no idea where to start debugging this.

Comment: Have you installed **Pillow** on Ubuntu?

Comment: of course, I have Pillow 2.3.0 installed

Comment: Also I don't think it is a problem with Apache because I get the same problem running the development server on Ububtu

Comment: I think the problem might be in the access to the media file folder. In development I use one, but on production it is served from a different location.

Comment: The image on my production server comes back as None

Comment: I've fixed the problem. The problem was with finding the location of the media folder which is different in production vs on the local dev server!

Comment: Would you mind telling us specifically how you solved it? I have the same problem

Comment: I solved it, but I wish I could remember how. It was a year ago. I believe it had something to with having the proper libraries in place. I would suggest you double check every detail of your installation, as well as checking permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the required packages:

```
sudo apt-get install libwebp4 libwebp4-dev libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev libjpeg8 libjpeg8-dev liblcms1 liblcms1-dev libwebp4 libwebp4-dev
```